# Sending SPL Token Exception

Tags: spl-token, solana-wallet-adapter, nextjs

I am attempting to transfer tokens when a user clicks a button. Once a user connects their wallet I have this method that gets called when a user clicks a button

```
  async function claimTokens() {
    setShowModal(false);
    setIsLoading(true);
    var data = await axios.get(`/api/claim?wallet=${wallet.publicKey.toBase58()}`)
    if(data.status != 200) 
    {
      notify({ type: 'error', message: `Error with our API, please retry in a few minutes` });
      return
    } else {
      let sig;
      try {
        var newTransaction = new Transaction();
        newTransaction.signatures = data.data.data.signers;
        newTransaction.instructions = data.data.data.instructions;
        newTransaction.recentBlockhash = data.data.data.recentBlockhash;
        newTransaction.feePayer = data.data.data.feePayer;
        console.log(newTransaction)
        sig = await sendTransaction(newTransaction, connection);
        notify({ type: 'error', message: `Claimed tokens!` });
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
      }
    }
  }
```

when I console.log the newTransaction it shows a transaction that looks like this [transaction screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8GXAQ.png)

When I call the API to get the transaction here is what the method looks like.

```
try {
    const connection = new web3.Connection(
      "OMITTING URL",
      'confirmed',
    );
    const { wallet } = req.query
    const key = <OMITTED-FOR-OBVIOUS-REASONS>
    const account = web3.Keypair.fromSeed(key.slice(0, 32));
    console.log(account.publicKey.toBase58())
    const wantedTokenAddress = new web3.PublicKey(process.env.TOKEN_ADDRESS)
    const transaction = new web3.Transaction()
    const toPublicKey = new web3.PublicKey(wallet);
    const tokenAccount = await getOrCreateAssociatedTokenAccount(
      connection,
      account,
      wantedTokenAddress,
      account.publicKey
    )
    let toATA = await splToken.getOrCreateAssociatedTokenAccount(
      connection,
      account,
      wantedTokenAddress,
      toPublicKey,
      false,
    ).catch(() => {/*nothing*/ });
    if (!toATA) {
      const associatedToken = await splToken.getAssociatedTokenAddress(
        wantedTokenAddress,
        account.publicKey,
        false,
        splToken.TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
        splToken.ASSOCIATED_TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID
      );
      transaction.add(
        splToken.createAssociatedTokenAccountInstruction(
          account.publicKey,
          associatedToken,
          account.publicKey,
          wantedTokenAddress,
          splToken.TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
          splToken.ASSOCIATED_TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID
        )
      );
    } else {
      transaction.add(
        splToken.createTransferInstruction(
          tokenAccount.address,
          toATA.address,
          account.publicKey,
          1,
          [],
          TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID
        )
      )
    }
    let blockhash = await (await connection.getLatestBlockhash('finalized')).blockhash;
    transaction.recentBlockhash = blockhash;
    transaction.feePayer = toPublicKey;
    transaction.sign(account)
    console.log(transaction)

    res.status(200).json({ data: transaction })
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error)
    res.status(500).json({ data: null })
  }
```

There error I am getting is when I try to send the transaction I am getting

> x.pubkey.toBase58 is not a function

That error is thrown inside of the sendTransaction method